# How to optimise pages loading time when there's a big database request (C# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, loading

I'm working on a big project. The project database contains a lot of data to display on the pages. When I want to access a page, it can take up to 15 seconds to fully load, which is way too slow.

I am using C# .NET 6, it's an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project using SQL Server.

I tried filtering Linq requests to import less data by pages; I tried to do pagination with HTML tables to display less data at the same time, but it's still very slow.

Here's an example of requests we're doing:

```
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var factures = _context.Factures
                           .AsNoTracking()
                           .Include(x => x.Chantiers)
                           .Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Annee) > 2020)
                           .Select(x => new FacturesViewModel()
                                            {
                                                // DATA HERE
                                            })
                           .ToList();

    return View(factures);
}
```

Does anyone know how I can improve the page load speed?

Comment: Use pagination...

Comment: I tried to do pagination with HTML tables to display less data at the same time, but it's still very slow, yes

Comment: Do you need the data from `Chantiers` right away? Could you load your data first, display a simplified version, and then lazy-load the associated `Chantiers` for each entry when requested by the user? Also, unless I'm missing something obvious, it seems that you're not using your `id` parameter at any point? Could you maybe filter out data using that `id` value?

Comment: Pagination is the right choice to manage a big amount of data on the client side. If the query is slow probably there is no appropriate index on the columns used to sort data. 
Since pagination use Take and Skip the OrderBy is required, since the database doesn't guarantee any order of returned data.

Comment: If the data isn't being updated consistently, could cache the results.

Also, I believe sql queries(IQueryable) have fractionally better performance than Linq statements, might be worth it for this use case.

Comment: Just want to point out a few things, ToList will pull everything immediately so make sure you paginate before that.  i think if you separate your C# function calls into a second query the first query will be server-side evaluated which is faster https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval,  and make sure you make use of EF navigation correctly when paginating https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of work, i found a solution

I used datatables ( https://datatables.net/ ) to do the pagination (only show 10 items each time), now the page loads much faster.

The ID parameter will also be used to order invoices in the list.